# Can I fit a glmer to data with only one subject?

Tags: r

I want to look at my pilot data and check that that materials are appropriate before running the main study. However, I only have one participant so far and I keep getting the same error message when I try to fit a Mixed Effects Model to Correct Recall and Extract the Estimated Probabilities.

Here is my R-Code:

```
#gmler for list 2 recall data (all responses)
L2recall_glmer <- glmer(L2_Correct ~ StatementType + (1 | Subject) + (1 | Topic), family = binomial, data = cued_recall, control = moreControl)

#Run ANOVA for List 2 recall for all item types
Anova(L2recall_glmer)

#Pairwise comparisons for List 2 recall for all items types
emmeans(L2recall_glmer, list(pairwise ~ StatementType), type = "response")
```

Here is the error

```
Error: grouping factors must have > 1 sampled level
```

Any idea how to surpass this? I will not be getting anymore pilot subjects for a month or so.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had to make the following change to the control component:

```
control = lmerControl(check.nlev.gtr.1 = "ignore"))
```